# Can i write a method which returns boolean as an expression

Tags: jsf

Can i write this:

```
<ui:repeat var="element" value="mybean.list">
<h:outputLink styleClass="#{myBean.otherList.contains(element)?'someclass':'someotherclass'}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is to wrap the `myBean.otherList.contains(element)` with another brackets () , like this `(myBean.otherList.contains(element))`

I do the same in several places

here an example

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{(appRow.application.file)?'attachmentFileExist':'attachmentFileNotExist'}"></h:panelGroup>
```

here is how your should look like

```
<ui:repeat var="element" value="mybean.list">
    <h:outputLink styleClass="#{(myBean.otherList.contains(element))?'someclass':'someotherclass'}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

again , not sure about the extra brackets , but I use them in my pages

in order to check you code use development tools of you browser or firebug and just click on the cell to see it style class